# getting class cast exception in pig UDF

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig, udf

I have a transposed data, i want to transpose it back to the original state.

```
eg: id  cd1  cd2
    1   x    a
    2   y    b
    3   z    c
```

Question 1 : when i write `input.get(0)` i get `id`, i am not able to access the row, i.e `1  x  a` as in the above table . So, **how to access the row?**

Question 2 : `DataBag dataBag = (DataBag) input.get(0)` gives me a **class cast exception**.My purpose of doing this is to attach an iterator over `Tuple`. Don't know how to resolve this exception.I have seen a few examples online and they were also doing the same but did not mention any such kind of exception. I have already written the `ouptut schema`.